# Add completion block when saving to user defaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am saving data to the user defaults using `NSKeyedArchiver`. 
Sometimes, there might be a small delay before the data is actually archived and saved, after calling my method to save the data.

I am reading this data from a Today's extension, and would like to update the extension once the data has been saved.

How can I add a completion block or something similar, to get notified when saving the data has completed?

Comment: Assuming the objects are immutable or thread safe, call NSKeyedArchiver on a background queue using grand central dispatch and have it send a message to the main thread when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't NSKeyedArchiver a synchronous operation ? You shouldn't have to wait for it to complete. It will proceed to the next line only after the data is completely archived.

NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(books, toFile: "/path/to/archive")

Worst case, you can use callbacks to do something after the archive operation is complete.

Comment: Is saving to the user defaults synchronous as well?

Comment: Yes, saving to NSUserDefaults is synchronous. So you might introduce a small pause into your UI. Getting that to happen in the background and call a completion block when it's finished is another question however.